# SPF-record / E-mail marked as spam in Gmail

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, gmail

E-mail send from my own e-mail (example@domain.nl) to a Gmail-account is marked as spam. When I view the e-mail headers you will see a softfail. I have tried to set the SPF-record for my domain, but I keep getting a softfail:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning example@domain.nl does not designate 2a02:348:83:cc40::1 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a02:348:83:cc40::1;
```

*2a02:348:83:cc40::1 = 141.138.204.64*

I have tried to set different SPF-records for the domainname: example.nl, an example:

```
v=spf1 ip4:141.138.204.64 ~all
```

What SPF-record to I need to set in order to 'pass' for the SPF?

Answer (score 1):

After reading more on Serverfault I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142369/create-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-spf-record) and I used the following SPF:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:XX.XX.X.XX ip6:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX ~all"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your spf to use the /64 network for performance, also be sure you have a valid PTR record and FCrDNS is configured for IPv4 and IPv6